# Methods returning values vs. those which don't

Tags: java

When you write methods you almost always have to check for things that must be valid.

Lets say you need to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the price argument on a method is invalid. Because I want to break my programs into small pieces I make a private method for it. However is it best practice to create a method that is named something like `validatePrize` and returns a boolean which I then check in an if statement where I invoke the `validatePrize` method, and then throw an IllegalArgumentException?

Or is it better that the method does not return anything and also throws the exception?

Answer (score 2):

I would say the answer to this is mainly based on preference. If you want a reusable function which doesn't throw an exception when called, then pick the validatePrize with a boolean return. If you are only using it to check for an exception, then use the validatePrize which throws an exception. In this case I would say that the validatePrize which throws an exception would be more suited, as it can be used for exception handling from outside the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends.

Firstly, `validatePrize` doesn't sound like a boolean method, so IMO it shouldn't return anything.

If you have a bunch of guard clauses, throw an exception. If you need validation across the app for the same collection of attributes, make it a method–but that method can also be used as part of the guard.

Comment: I'm still a noob but it is just a matter of renaming the method to isPrizeValid (to get around it) :P

Comment: @LewsTherin Obviously. But then that's *all* it should do; it shouldn't have secondary side effects that go beyond determining if it's valid or not. I answered the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know that a negative value is an invalid argument, you can guard against it by doing :

```
if(val < 0)
{
  return false;
}
```

I've read in books that guarding against such a situation is the best way to go. It isn't or doesn't meet "an exception criteria". So yeah I would just return a boolean.

Some like to throw exceptions though, but it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do delegate the check to a method, you could as well throw an exception from that method directly to avoid clutter code in your constructor. This is a typical approach used by guava's `Preconditions`:

```
this.value = Preconditions.checkNotNull(value, "value must not be null");
```

this line will throw an NullPointerException with the associated message if the argument is null. If the argument is not null, it returns the argument which enables to check and assign the argument in one line.

If you are interested, this is what the [code looks like](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java?r=44):

```
public static <T> T checkNotNull(T reference, Object errorMessage) {
  if (reference == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException(String.valueOf(errorMessage));
  }
  return reference;
}
```

You could use a similar approach for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

My own opinion about this is that exceptions should only be thrown if something in **unexpected**. A null pointer can be this, or a negative number for an ID (which should always be positive). Basically, an exception is used to show a problem inside your program. If you're simply validating a user's input, use booleans and tests.